# Jump to the definition in a scss file

Tags: key-bindings, filetype, ctags

How, in vim, can I jump to the mixin that is `@include`ed in a SCSS file?

For example, I'd like to put the cursor over `avatar` below and hit some magic key in vim that'll take me to that mixin...but how?

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application/_global.scss

...
.avatar {
  @include avatar(50px);
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
...
```

**ctags** doesn't pick it up.

And typing `gf` yields error: `Can't find file "avatar.rb" in path`. Which makes me wonder if I might be able to add `.scss` as a suffix that `gf` will consider because the file I want to jump to is `avatar.scss`?!?

I've tried `:set suffixesadd+=.scss` to no effect. thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

### `gf`

The default `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/scss.vim` sources `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/sass.vim` which already sets everything for you to do `gf` over `avatar` and jump to `avatar.css`:

```
setlocal suffixesadd=.sass,.scss,.css
setlocal includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'\\%(.*/\\\|^\\)\\zs','_','')
```

See:

```
:help gf
:help 'includeexpr'
:help 'suffixesadd'
```

### definition search

It is also supposed to set everything for doing `[<C-d>` over `avatar` and jump to the definition of the mixin but there seems to be a problem with the default `includeexpr` that prevents the otherwise correctly recognized includes to be correctly processed. Resetting that option fixes the issue:

```
setlocal includeexpr=
```

Adding the line above to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/scss.vim` should do the trick.

The relevant lines in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/sass.vim` are:

```
setlocal define=^\\s*\\%(@mixin\\\|=\\)
setlocal includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'\\%(.*/\\\|^\\)\\zs','_','')
setlocal suffixesadd=.sass,.scss,.css
let &l:include = '^\s*@import\s\+\%(url(\)\=["'']\='
```

See:

```
:help 'define'
:help 'includeexpr'
:help 'suffixesadd'
:help 'include'
:help :let-&
:help definition-search
```

### ctags

If you use ctags, adding the lines below to `~/.ctags` will give you a reasonably good sass support:

```
--langdef=scss
--langmap=scss:.scss
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]*@mixin ([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/m,mixin,mixins/
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]*\$([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/v,variable,variables/
--regex-scss=/^([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)*(\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]+) *[,{]/\2/c,class,classes/
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]+) *[,{]/\1/c,class,classes/
--regex-scss=/^(.*)*\#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+) *[,{]/\2/i,id,ids/
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]*#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/i,id,ids/
--regex-scss=/(^([A-Za-z0-9_-])*([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)) *[,|\{]/\1/t,tag,tags/
--regex-scss=/(^([^\/\/])*)[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)) *[,|\{]/\3/t,tag,tags/
--regex-scss=/(^(.*, *)([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)) *[,|\{]/\3/t,tag,tags/
--regex-scss=/(^[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)) *[,|\{]/\1/t,tag,tags/
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]*@media\s+([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/d,media,media/
```

See:

```
:help tags
:help ctags
$ man ctags
```

Here is a demo of the three methods above, in the same order:

[image: scss]

Comment: Can you expand on your `gf` section (i'll get to others later). I'm typing `gf` over "avatar" and…nothing. Can you tell he how to check if my "defaults" are configured as you mention?

Comment: FWIW: `:setlocal includeexpr` -> `includeexpr=rails#includeexpr(v:fname)`

Comment: That `includeexpr` is wrong, rails.vim has no business defining that for non-ruby/rails files and I suspect `suffixesadd` is wrong too. Also, see my edit.

Comment: FYI: while editing a .scss file `:set suffixesadd` -> `suffixesadd=.sass,.scss,.css`